# Search filtering - DropDownLists and TextBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on some web app and on one of my content pages I require a search function. I use 2 DropDownLists (one for category and one for search parameters) and a TextBox.

Problem is, when I select value from ddlCategory I need a postback (because it filters the data from a database that is displayed i.e. parts, assemblies...). If there is nothing in the TextBox (no text to search for), I have no problem. But when there is some text in the TextBox, it is cleared and again all the data in that category is displayed and I need to enter search parameters again. Do you understand what is the problem? :) How can this be fixed?

Here is the relevant code:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbSrch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSrch" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSrch" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="btnSrch_Click" />

        //here is code behind:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView(); //bind data from SQL DB to GV

        if (Session["ddlCategory"] != null)  //I need a persistent dropdown list
        {                                   
            BindDropDownLists();
            ddlCategory.SelectedValue = (string)Session["ddlCategory"];
        }
        else
        {
            BindDropDownLists();
        }
    }
}

private void BindGridView()
{
      //Get data from database based on Category and search parameters and bind it to the GV
}

private void BindDropDownLists()  //bind DDLs
{
    ddlKategorija.Items.Add("Value1");
    ddlKategorija.Items.Add("Value2");
    ddlKategorija.Items.Add("Value3");
    ddlKategorija.Items.Add("Value4");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    da.Fill(table);

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        ddlSrch.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
}

protected void btnSrch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGridView();
}

protected void ddlKategorija_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ddlCategory"] = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);`. That will load the page from fresh and empty your text box.

On `ddlKategorija_SelectedIndexChanged` event the page has already posted back. At this point your controls including the textbox have been repopulated from ViewState. By doing a redirect at this point you are reloading the page again but this time as if it has been loaded for the very first time. Thus all you controls will be blank.

Just delete the `Response.Redirect` line and all will be well.

Comment: you are right, it does the trick. I had that refresh there because I wanted to refresh GridView everytime I selected diferent Category for the displayed data... no problem, will design my "search bar" little diferent and it'll work just as well. thnx